# How to return variable from Promise in my example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I have a problem with the next code:

```
const Header = () => {

 let min = 0;
 let sec = 0;

 timeRemaining().then(res => {
    getCountdown();
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
      getCountdown();
    }, 1000);
    function getCountdown() {
      var current_date = new Date().getTime();
      var seconds_left = (res.data - current_date) / 1000;
      let minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
      let seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);
      if (minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      return {min = minutes sec = seconds}; // The poblem is here

    }
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{seconds}</p>
      <p>{minutes}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to set values min and sec in my problems, but can't. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: They are both `const`, so you cannot set them.

Comment: Also, you cannot have two `return` statements - the first one will execute and the function ends - the second one will never be reached.

Comment: The callback in `.then()` is invoked asynchronously, so the outer `return` will have already been invoked. You'll need to use the `useState()` hook to initialize `min` and `sec` and set them asynchronously, triggering a re-render.

Comment: problem 1: the value resolved in a Promise is only available INSIDE `.then` (or async/await, but lets not consider that, it's just syntax sugar for promises) ... problem 2: your getCountdown function  is in a setInterval callback, so any returned value is unavailable .... problem 3: the code implies you want `Header` to return a value, every second, on a single call, which is not possible. Have you considered using callbacks

Comment: Are you using stateful react components as classes or functions + hooks? You need to initialize this process in a lifecycle event for classes or in a hook.

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, let's look into your code for understanding some things.**

The first thing that is important to note here is that your component `Header` is a **function component**.

Function components don't have state, they're known as dumb components because they just get props as input and render something as output. What does that mean? It means that using a promise inside your component does not have any effect because your promise is going to resolve after the component is already rendered.

What you could do for solving that? You could use a [stateful class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class), or even better, you could use [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) for handling state inside a function component. But keep in mind that in both cases, you should keep a state for your data.

---

**The second thing that is important to note is that your code has some mistakes:**

In your first `return` statement, you're setting your variable `min` to receive the value from `minutes`, and then returning it. (*The second return statement isn't going to reach anyway because the first return will finish the function*).

But your `min` variable is declared as `const`, so you cannot attribute a value to it after its declaration.

Also, you're trying to access `minutes` and `seconds` outside the function where they were declared. It's not possible.

---

**Conclusion:**

Your code has the correct idea but it's implemented in a wrong way. Try the links I sent you, and you'll probably solve this problem in the right way in minutes.

:)

Comment: **Edit Note**: `Functional` to `Function` [Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)